# Why isn't get_query_var returning my custom query vars?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am building a WP plugin which defines some extra URLs, query vars and templates.

I want to use `get_query_var("wps_service_id");` in my templates, but it is returning nothing no matter what I do.

I have whitelisted the extra query vars [like the documentation explains](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/#custom-query-vars):

```
add_filter('query_vars', function ($query_vars) {
    $query_vars[] = 'wps_service_id';
    return $query_vars;
});
```

I am defining my extra URLs and loading the correct template like this:

```
add_action('init',  function () {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'services/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$',
        'index.php?wps_service_id=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
});


add_action('parse_request', function (&$wp) {
    if (array_key_exists('wps_service_id', $wp->query_vars)) {
        require plugin_dir_path(__DIR__) . "views/service.php";
        exit();
    }
    return;
});
```

The template is loading, so WP is clearly reading and interpreting the query vars to some extent. Why can't I read it and use it in the template using `get_query_var`?

Comment: Weirdly, if I use `print_r($wp->query_vars);` in the template, I CAN see my custom query vars. what gives?

Answer (score 0):

Is it correct to use 'array_key_exists' ? You should use 'in_array', because you assign a value not a key in  $query_vars[] = 'wps_service_id';

Check with:

```
error_log( array_key_exists('wps_service_id', $wp->query_vars));
error_log( in_array('wps_service_id', $wp->query_vars));
```